# Is there a way to create a unique ID using Node.js without additional modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, uuid

In my Node.js application I need a unique ID - it need to be a UUID or something like that, just unique (auto-incrementing a number is *not* unique enough ;-)).

At the moment I am using [node-uuid](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid), but I'm curious whether there is a way of how to achieve this without an additional module.

I though about using a timestamp, but that's not unique (as several calls to `+Date()` may happen in the same millisecond.

Any other idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: I think nobody would create node-uuid if there was any other native solutions to solve this problem...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jed/982883

Comment: Maybe take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Comment: If you don't care about RFC compliance (or other standards compliance), combining a random # (32+ bits of randomness) and a timestamp (unique value changes every 1-16 msecs) is a decent start.  E.g `Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2)`